# how do you re-open a php session after it's closed?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session

Sort of a noob question, but I'm writing a board game where the state of the board, along with other game state information, are being stored as php session variables. The board is rendered with html/jquery. Every turn an ajax call is made to php to execute logic to change the state of the board. But every ajax call, it would seem a new php session is opened and the old one is forgotten.  Here's the code:

```php
'index.php'
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'cycle.php',
        data: {},
        dataType: 'json',       
        success: function(data, status, jqXHR) {    
            var stuff = jQuery.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);
            $("#board").html(stuff.html);       
        },
    }); 


'cycle.php'
        <?php 
session_start();
include('functions.php');
header('Content-type: application/json');

if (!isset($_session['turn'])) {

    $_session['turn'] = 1;
    $_session['population'] = "";
    $out = write_table();   
    $out['turn'] = $_session['turn'];
    $out = json_encode($out);
    echo $out;
}
else {
    $_session['turn'] = 2;
    $out = turn($_session['population']);
    $out['turn'] = $_session['turn'];
    $out = json_encode($out);
    echo $out;
}




?>
```

Comment: "it would seem a new php session is opened and the old one is forgotten" - if your server is set up correctly, that should not be happening.  The whole point of sessions is to persist data across http requests.

Comment: If you're 'losing' your session, then check the cookie settings and make sure that the session ID stored in th session cookie remains constant between requests. new ID = new session.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try `$_SESSION` instead of `$_session`.  All PHP variable names are [case sensitive](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php)

Comment: You beat me for a few seconds! +1

Answer (score 1):

It should be automatic when you call `session_start()` as long as you are not calling `session_destroy()`

There must be something deeper going on with your code/setup for this to be occurring.

Perhaps check your session-related PHP INI settings.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, i'll look into this .. do you know what php ini setting in particular might causing this?